# How can Quartus Prime System Console be used to read/write a whole file?

Tags: debugging, intel-fpga, quartus

I want to find a way to read/write whole file from/to my Intel FPGA design. The file being written provides data to be processed and the file being read shall contain the results of the processing task.

Is there a way to read/write a whole file worth of data into the FPGA design using SystemConsole tool in Quartus? If so, how?

You could say, why not just read/write one byte at a time into some memory block? You are correct. However, what I am trying to get at is, if there is a built in supported way to do file I/O itself via tcl commands.

Comment: If you designed it then you should know how it works?

Comment: This is a general question to understand how someone would go about doing this.

Comment: It may be a general question but the answer MUST be specific to a particular design on a particular FPGA. For example if you integrated an Ethernet MAC the answer will involve connecting to its MAC address and then whatever protocol you chose between that and the relevant memory (BlockRam or DDR) where you want the data to live. If you implemented a PCIE target interface, it involves PCIE accesses via the host's PCIE driver to the target's PCIE address space. If you implemented an RS232 interface, ... you get the picture but it'll take a while. And if you didn't ... start over.

Comment: Are you talking about a file that will become part of the FPGA design itself -- i.e., you write the file and then run synthesis? Or are you talking about having the FPGA already running the synthesized design and pushing data through it from the host PC? You need to be a lot more specific about what it is you're trying to do.

Comment: ok lets take an exampl; suppose there is an image compression algorithm implemented on an FPGA. We want to write the test image into it from the PC and then read the resulting compressed image file. What is the proper way to do this from system console in Quartus?

Comment: You still haven't told us what I/O interfaces are implemented in this image compressor. But the answer is : interface to them.

Comment: See if I want to use SystemConsole it means that everything is either AvanlonMM or AvalonST.